# How to use reduce on dictionary in Python

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I have two classes - Item and AIShoppingCart (which has dictionary, for example {"milk" : *Item*(2, 2.28, 1)}). I have to find the most likable item from my cart using reduce and I am not allowed to use max(). Unfortunately, my program throws an error

> <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

---

```
class Item:
def __init__(self,quantity,price,likable):
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.price = price
    self.likable = likable

class AIShoppingCart(ShoppingCart):
def __init__(self,items):
    super().__init__(items)
def add_item(self,name,quantity,price):
    if name in self.items:
        self.items[name].likable+=1
        self.items[name].quantity+=quantity
    else:
        items[name]=Item(quantity,price,1)

def findMostLikable(self):
    return reduce(lambda x:self.items[x].likable>1, self.items)
```

---

How should I use reduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look up the documentation for `reduce`. If you do `reduce(f, [a, b, c, d])` this will essentially be applied as `f(f(f(a, b), c), d)` -- so reduce essentially takes 2 elements at a time and reduces them to 1.

In your case the reduce function just has to pick the greater element by value:

```py
return reduce(lambda a, b: a if a[1].likable >= b[1].likable else b,
              self.items.items())
```

The `.items()` function gets your dictionary's key-value pairs as a list of tuples, whose value I get using `a[1]`/`b[1]` -- the returned result is a key-value-tuple.

If you just want the maximum value, without caring about the keys:

```py
return reduce(lambda a, b: a if a.likable >= b.likable else b,
              self.items.values()).likable
```

Comment: I get it, but I cannot solve how to compare the items by the likable property.

Comment: That would be `a[1].likable`, I'll update my answer, sorry about that

Comment: I am getting the following error ('eggs', <Item.Item object at 0x000001EA58C43908>) But yes, it almost works. The output should be eggs's likable count.

Comment: That's not an error, that's the result. You can add `[1].likable` to the very end to get just the value, but in that case you can just iterate over the `.values()` directly. I'll update my answer.